# Mongomapper is referencing db using name causing ReferenceError issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

This is the query generated by Mongomapper:

```
MONGODB mydatabase['users'].find({:name=>"bob"}).limit(-1)
```

But this is not valid in the mongo console since the correct syntax is

```
db.users.find({:name=>"bob"}).limit(-1)
```

If I just use the generated one, I got this error in the console

```
Thu Jan 12 03:01:23 ReferenceError: mydatabase is not defined (shell):1
```

Is there any way to make it correct? This causes my rails application broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not mongodb's issue. 406 is pretty much relating to the controller call.

I need to use:

```
render :json => @user
```

rather than

```
respond_to
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use symbols in the MongoDB console as they are ruby and not javascript :-) Try this:

```
db.users.find({name: "bob"}).limit(-1)
```

Comment: The problem is this is generated by MongoMapper.

Comment: Yep, thats the logging output of mongomapper in the console. You can't run the output directly in the mongo shell though.